# Prove that $ t^t + t^{ t + 1} - t^{ t + 2} \le 1 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Prove that $ (x + 1)^{x + 1} + (x + 1)^{x + 2} - (x + 1)^{x + 3} \le 1 $. Here $ x > -1 $.

Let $ x + 1 = t $ we have that $ t^t + t^{ t + 1} - t^{ t + 2} \le
1 $ which gives $ t^t ( 1 + t - t^2) \le 1 $ so $ 1 + t - t^2 \le t^{-t} $. I am stuck here, how can I proceed via Bernoulli's inequality ?  Please suggest elementary approaches, e.g. using Bernoulli's inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to prove that, for all $t > 0$,
$$\frac{1}{t^t} \ge 1 + t - t^2. \tag{1}$$

If $0 < t \le 1$, by Bernoulli inequality, we have
$$\frac{1}{t^t} - (1 + t - t^2)
\ge \frac{1}{1 + (t - 1)t} - (1 + t - t^2) = \frac{t^2(t - 1)^2}{t^2 - t + 1}\ge 0.$$

If $1 < t < 2$, by Bernoulli inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{t^t} - (1 + t - t^2)
 &= \frac{1}{t^{t-1}t} - (1 + t - t^2)\\
 &\ge \frac{1}{[1 + (t - 1)(t - 1)]t} - (1 + t - t^2)\\
 &= \frac{(t^3 - t^2 + 1)(t - 1)^2}{(t^2 - 2t + 2)t}\\
 &\ge 0.
\end{align*}

If $t \ge 2$, we have $1 + t - t^2 < 0$, clearly (1) is true.

We are done.

Comment: Thank you can you help again please https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4786788/1234702

Answer (score 1):

Using the Bernoulli inequality you can prove that $1+t$ is always less than $t^2$ when $t$ is greater than $1$, which means $1+t-t^2$ is less than $0$ when $t$ is greater than $1$, but $t^{-t}$ is always positive when $t>0$, so your inequality is easily provable when $t$ is greater than $1$ , but I can't solve for you fully.

Comment: Actually, $1+t-t^2$ doesn't become negative until $t$ exceeds the golden ratio.