# How do we prove $ x^{x^x} \ge 2 x^x - x^{x+1} - x^{x-2} + 1 $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

For all positive reals prove that $ x^{x^x} \ge 2 x^x - x^{x+1} - x^{x-2} + 1 $

My simplifications

$ x^{x^x} \ge 2 x^x - x^{x+1} - x^{x-2} + 1 = x^x(2 - x - \frac {1}{x^2}) + 1 = x^{x-2} (2x^2 - x^3 - 1) + 1 = x^{x - 2}(1 - x)(x^2 - x - 1) + 1 $

This is practice of the Bernoulli's inequality. But I couldn't find a way to use it.

Comment: looks a bit like $(1+(x-1))^{x^x} \geq 1 + x^x (x-1)$ is $x^x(x-1) \geq x^{x-2} (1-x)(x^2-x-1)$?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, $x^{x^x} \ge  x \ge 2 x^x - x^{x+1} - x^{x-2} + 1$ for all $x > 0$ (and the left inequality is easy).

Comment: @MartinR Can you expand please ? Or posting answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can prove that
$$
 x^{x^x} \ge x \ge 2 x^x - x^{x+1} - x^{x-2} + 1
$$
holds for all $x > 0$.

*Proof of the left inequality:* $x^{x^x} \ge x$ is equivalent to
$$
 (x^x -1) \ln(x) \ge 0
$$
and that is true for all $x > 0$ because both factors are simultaneously negative, zero, or positive.

*Proof of the right inequality:* We need to show that
$$ \tag{$*$}
 x^x (1+x-x^2)(x-1) \le x^2(x-1)
$$
holds for all $x > 0$. This surely holds for $x=1$, and also for $x \ge (1+\sqrt 5)/2$ because then the left-hand side is negative or zero. It remains to consider the cases $0<x<1$ and $1 < x < (1+\sqrt 5)/2$:

**Case 1:** $0 < x < 1$. We need to show that
$$
 x^x(1+x-x^2) \ge x^2
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
 x^{2-x} \le 1+x-x^2 \, .
$$
From Bernoulli's inequality we get
$$
 x^{2-x} = x (1+(x-1))^{1-x} \le x(1+(1-x)(x-1)) = x^2(2-x)
$$
so that it suffices to show that
$$
 x^2(2-x) \le 1+x-x^2
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
 (1-x)(1+2x-x^2) \ge 0 \, .
$$
That is true because $1+2x-x^2 = 1+x(2-x) \ge 0$.

**Case 2:** $1 < x < (1+\sqrt 5)/2$.  We need to show that
$$
 x^x(1+x-x^2) \le x^2 \, .
$$
Bernoulli's inequality now gives
$$
 x^x = x x^{x-1} \le x(1+(x-1)^2)
$$
so that it suffices to show that
$$ 
\bigl (1 + (x-1)^2 \bigr) \cdot \bigl( 1+x-x^2\bigr) \le x \, .
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
 (x-1) (x^3-2x^2+x+2) \ge 0
$$
and that is true because $x^3-2x^2+x+2 = x(x-1)^2+2 > 0$.

Comment: +1 Thank you !  I also upvoted River Li's answer. I'm accepting your answer here because honestly I found your answer very easy to follow.

Comment: @MartinR, if you prove that the function $\phi(x)=2x^x-x^{x+1}-x^{x-2}+1$ is concave and its tangent line at $x=1$ is $y=x$, you are done because it implies the right inequality. Could you do it?

Comment: @Angelo: I had thought about it, and plotting the function and its second derivative strongly indicates that is *is* concave. But the second derivative does not look “nice” and I did not see an immediate proof that it is negative. Therefore I came up with the above solution (also because the question mentions a “practice of the Bernoulli's inequality”).

Answer (score 3):

assuming you're dealing with the generalized Bernoulli's inequality, which would be $$(1+y)^n \geq 1+ny, \forall n \geq 1, y \geq -1$$

you could do:

$$(1+(x-1))^{x^x} \geq 1 + x^x(x-1)$$

and all you need now is to check that for $x \geq 0$ it holds that:

$$x^x(x-1) \geq x^{x-2}(1-x)(x^2-x-1)$$ multiply it by $x^2$ on both sides: $$x^2(x-1) \geq (1-x)(x^2-x-1) \iff (x-1)(2x^2-x-1) \geq 0 \iff \\\iff(x-1)^2(2x+1) \geq0$$

which is true. Now we need to check for $0 <x <1$

Comment: But this is not correct $\forall n>0$

Comment: @User would you agree it is true for any positive rational?

Comment: This is true only for $x^x > 1$

Comment: @User ah, you're correct, so I proved it is true for $x \geq 1$

Answer (score 3):

The desired inequality is written as
$$x^{x^x - x} \ge 2 - x - \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^x}.\tag{1}$$

**Case 1.** $x \ge 1$

We have $x^x \ge x$. We have
$$\mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS}\ge
x^{x - x} - \left(2 - x - \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x}\right) = \frac{(x + 1)(x - 1)^2}{x^2} \ge 0.$$

**Case 2.** $0 < x < 1$

By Bernoulli inequality, we have $x^x - x 
\le 1 + (x - 1)x - x \le 1 - x$,
and $\frac{1}{x^x}= \frac{x^{1-x}}{x}
\le \frac{1 + (x - 1)(1 - x)}{x} = 2 - x$. It suffices to prove that
$$x^{1 - x}
\ge 2 - x - \frac{1}{x^2} + (2 - x). \tag{2}$$

By Bernoulli inequality, we have
$x^{1 - x}
= \frac{x}{x^x} \ge \frac{x}{1 + (x - 1)x} $. It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{x}{1 + (x - 1)x} \ge 2 - x - \frac{1}{x^2} + (2 - x)$$
or
$$\frac{(2x^3 - 2x^2 + x + 1)(x-1)^2}{(x^2 - x + 1)x^2}\ge 0$$
which is clearly true.

We are done.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @User You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hi a hint using Bernoulli's inequality:

$$x^{1+x^{x}-1}\ge\frac{\left(1+\left(x-1\right)\left(1+x^{x}\right)\right)}{x}$$

Could you proceed from here ?

Comment: Hi, but this is not correct $\forall x>0$

Comment: @User is it a joke ?

Comment: @User $$x^{x-2}-x^{\left(x-1\right)}+x^{\left(x+1\right)}-x^{x}\geq 0\to x^{-2}-x^{-1}+x^{+1}-1\geq 0,\forall x>0$$

Comment: It is a nice proof. (+1) I rewrote it as follows: By Bernoulli inequality, we have
$$\mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS}
= \frac{x^{1 + x^x}}{x} - (2x^x - x^{x+1} - x^{x-2} + 1)$$
$$\ge \frac{1 + (x - 1)(1 + x^x)}{x}
- (2x^x - x^{x+1} - x^{x-2} + 1)
$$
$$= \frac{x^x(x+1)(x-1)^2}{x^2}\ge 0.$$ One my let $u = x^x$ for easier to get the last step.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function

$$f(x)=x^{x^x} -( 2 x^x - x^{x+1} - x^{x-2} + 1)$$

Its first derivative is
$$x^{x-3} \left(x^4-x^3+x-2+x^{x^x+2}+\log (x) \left(x^4-2 x^3+x^{x^x+3}
   (\log (x)+1)+x\right)\right)$$ which cancels for $x=1$ (as $f(x)$ does too). At this point the second derivative has a value of $6$.

So, $x=1$ corresponds to a minimum value of the function.

What would remain to prove is that $x=1$ is the only zero of the first derivative.